# how to group testcases in CoAP conformance test suite

Tags: networking, testing, protocols, standards-compliance, coap

I am writing a conformance test suite for [Constrained Application Protocol (CoAP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-core-coap/) based on TTCN-3. Now I've already known the protocol. CoAP is similar to HTTP. They are both application layer protocols. There are CoAP client and CoAP server, they communicate using messages. Now I am beginning to write the test suite. But I am having trouble in how I can design the whole test suite, because there may be too many test cases. To ensure I design a complete test suite, before writing each test case, it is necessary to group the test cases. How am I going to group these test cases? Anyone can give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is your work available in public? I'm interested in coap implementation for tiny devices and need some test suite.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are many ways to organize your test suite.

A good approach is to first identify **what is need to be tested** before starting to think **how it can be tested**. I would suggest having a look at [how ETSI validates and tests communication protocols](https://www.etsi.org/images/files/Brochures/Intro-achieving-technical-excellence-brochure.pdf).

More focussing on CoAP testing, you may be get inspired by available tests suites online, such as:

- The [iottestware.coap](https://github.com/eclipse/iottestware.coap) project
- The [tests of the libocoap project](https://github.com/obgm/libcoap/tree/develop/tests)

Good luck!